# Not able use uiautomatorviewer when phone is connected over wifi

Tags: android, ui-automation, uiautomatorviewer

I am trying to automate one android device and i don't have USB access for the device .But i am able connect over wifi using "adb connect ipaddress:5555".After connecting device over wifi, i am trying to inspect element using uiautomatorviewer But uiautomatorviewer is not loading the xml dump and device screenshot.[image]

Comment: Are you able to do other things with `adb`, such as `adb push` or `adb pull` or `adb logcat` or `adb shell`?

Comment: Yeah I am able to do adb push ,pull and etc without any issues